# how to identify download bar in Microsoft edge browser with UFT15

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

My requirement is that I need to save the downloaded file in some dynamic location and for that I want to click on 'save as' option available in download bar. However the **UFT one(15.02)** is unable to identify the download bar in **Microsoft Edge browser (v87 64-bit)**. I tried with UI Automation add-in as well but with UI Automation as well , UFT 15.02 is not identifying download bar not 'save as' button present in the bar. Is there any way by which I can click on save as option button present in download bar in Microsoft edge browser using UFT 15.02??

below is the image of download bar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for it to click on 'Save As' button on Microsoft edge browser. Hope it is useful to you guys.

```
Window("regexpwndclass:=Chrome_WidgetWin_1","regexpwndtitle:= Microsoft Edge").Activate    
    Set x = createobject("wscript.shell")    
    x.SendKeys "{F6}"    
    wait 1    
    x.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"    
    x.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"    
    x.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

With this focus is coming on 'Save As' button and using enter i am able to click on it.

thanks